# RSS feed issue. How to pass html5 AUDIO tag?

Tags: jquery, html, rss, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have a feed created using Drupal views which I am passing to an HTML5 web app using RSS.

I have three separate feeds going (for three separate pages in the web app). They all work great except for one, the one that contains the HTML5 audio tag.

I have tried various systems and all give the same output, the title, the text from the body, but no music player. I know the music player is being passed because if i plug the feed into google feedburner then Everything is displayed perfectly, music player included.

The feed as it should be:

Here is the xml that is being generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><rss version="2.0" xml:base="http://logan-net.com/demos12354688532" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"          xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <channel>
  <title>demos</title>
  <link>http://logan-net.com/demos12354688532</link>
  <description></description>
  <language>en</language>
      <item>
<title>Make It Happen</title>
<link>http://logan-net.com/node/33</link>
<description>&lt;div class=&quot;field field-name-body field-type-text-with-summary field-label-hidden&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-items&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;field-item even&quot; property=&quot;content:encoded&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;One of the first songs in the new batch of demos recorded by Kenny and Mick.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;

 &lt;p&gt;&lt;audio controls=&quot;controls&quot;&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;source src=&quot;http://logan-net.com/sites/default/files/Make%20It%20Happen.mp3&quot; type=&quot;audio/mp3&quot;&gt;&lt;/source&gt;&lt;/audio&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
 &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;</description>
 <pubDate>Tue, 20 Nov 2012 23:01:30 +0000</pubDate>
 <dc:creator>admin</dc:creator>
  <guid isPermaLink="false">33 at http://logan-net.com</guid>
  </item>
  </channel>
  </rss>
```

and here is the HTML from the source of the feed:

```
   <audio controls="controls">
    <source src="http://logan-net.com/sites/default/files/Make%20It%20Happen.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source></audio>
```

Full HTML from the page that is pulling in the feed:

```
<html class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta name="generator" content=
  "HTML Tidy for Linux/x86 (vers 11 February 2007), see www.w3.org" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

  <title>Logan</title>
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href=
  "img/touch/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href=
  "img/touch/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href=
  "img/touch/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href=
  "img/touch/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/touch/apple-touch-icon.png" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <!-- iPhone (Retina) -->
  <link href="img/apple-touch-startup-image-640x920.png" media=
  "(device-width: 320px) and (device-height: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"
  rel="apple-touch-startup-image" />
  <!-- This script prevents links from opening in Mobile Safari. https://gist.github.com/1042026 -->
  <!--
        <script>(function(a,b,c){if(c in b&&b[c]){var d,e=a.location,f=/^(a|html)$/i;a.addEventListener("click",function(a){d=a.target;while(!f.test(d.nodeName))d=d.parentNode;"href"in d&&(d.href.indexOf("http")||~d.href.indexOf(e.host))&&(a.preventDefault(),e.href=d.href)},!1)}})(document,window.navigator,"standalone")</script>
        -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/add2home.css" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><!--  <script src="js/add2home.js"></script> -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="feed"></div>

  <div id="musichome">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
  </div><!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script src="js/vendor/zepto.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><script src="js/helper.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.7/full/jquery.tools.min.js" type=
"text/javascript">
</script><script src="rss/jquery.zrssfeed.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script><!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
            var _gaq=[["_setAccount","UA-XXXXX-X"],["_trackPageview"]];
            (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;
            g.src=("https:"==location.protocol?"//ssl":"//www")+".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,"script"));
  //]]>
  </script><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
                        $(document).ready(function () {
                          $('#feed').rssfeed('http://logan-net.com/mp3s.xml', {
                            limit: 5,
                            date: false,
                            header: false,
                            snippet: false,
                            sortasc: true,
                            limit: 3
                          });
                        });
  //]]>
  </script><!-- javascript coding -->
  &#226;&#8364;&#8249;
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: RSS isn't really HTML 5, even if some viewers agree to render HTML tags when they encounter them. Where are you viewing this stream? Maybe you should choose a different format?

Comment: I am trying to view it in my web app. everything is working great except the <AUDIO> tag. I know that the proper feed can be viewed in a browser because it renders fine in google feedburner and various others i've looked at.

Comment: What does the HTML source code look like in your web app? What code does your app use to show the RSS?

Comment: updated with HTML source. I am using zrssfeed from Zazar. This is the live page http://wearelogan.com/news.html

Comment: No, I mean what does the HTML of the video tag look like when it enters the page? What are you seeing instead of the video?

Comment: Updated... the thing is, it does work. if you view the feed at feedburner it all displays fine. music player included. By the way I am appreciating your help!

Comment: you can see what i am seeing here, this is the page: http://wearelogan.com/news.html

Comment: You might want to look at the [<enclosure>](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#element-channel-item-enclosure) element in the RSS spec.